# How to can I upgrade Xcode 4.1 to 4.5.2 properly?

Tags: upgrade, mac-appstore, xcode, macos

I'm trying to get Xcode up to date... but i think i have a little problem.

I go in the Mac App Store. I find Xcode. I click on free button, it asks me to connect with my Apple-ID. Done.

I get the "install" button... I click and nothing happens. I have a loader spinning during few seconds at the right of buttons Prev/Next in the top bar... but nothing else.

Where is a process bar ? Mac App says to me that Xcode takes 1.50 GB but is downloading ? How can I follow the download ? Is really downloading ? Do I have to uninstall the Xcode 4.1 ?

I am a bit lost with the changes to this program and the new App Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside whether you are actually done with the prior version of Xcode (as older versions have some capabilities and older SDK that the newer versions no longer support - you might want to keep an old machine with an old Xcode around if you are supporting legacy software products - but let's assume you don't care about anything other than making new programs with the newest Xcode) let's dive in with the steps.

To prepare for the new Xcode, it is *easiest to uninstall all previous versions* of Xcode by following the uninstall documentation for each version you have installed.

For Xcode 4.1 you will want to run the perl script to clean things up:

### Uninstalling Xcode Developer Tools

To uninstall Xcode developer tools on the boot volume along with the  directory, from a Terminal window type:

```
$ sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

[image: App Store download indication is "Installing"]

For the new Xcode, the App Store doesn't normally show the download progress so you must track it from [Launchpad](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5548) or just by watching the /Applications folder in Finder. It shows **INSTALLING** as depicted above, but the Launchpad view has a live progress bar and summary of the 1.61 GB download as depicted below.

[image: Launchpad showing an App Store download in progress for Xcode]

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm. But I'm disapointed, there is no emulator for iPad 3 in this new Xcode ... Do you know how can I emulate an ipad 3 for testing my html/css templates ?

Comment: The retina iPad works to duplicate the third and fourth generation iPad. Make sure your display can handle 2048 vertical pixels in portrait. You will be able to scroll around if you don't have all the pixels you need. For reference, here is what the iPad (Retina) in iOS simulator looks like on my Cinema Display set at 1920x1200 - [first a portion](http://cl.ly/KvzS), then [the whole screen...](http://cl.ly/Kvvv)

Answer (score 1):

I just want to share my experience. I started the 4.5.2 Xcode install from the the Mac App Store and the message *Installing* was displayed for about 25 minutes while it installed 4.5.2.

However, I did not have an Xcode icon in LaunchPad to track the progress. Also, Xcode in Finder had the old file date until the upgrade was finished.

So I had no clue aside from hearing my hard drive spin a few times, that there was progress until the Mac App Store message was changed to *Installed* when the upgrade was completed.

The good news though is that my patience paid off and Xcode 4.5.2 was successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reasons why you cannot download the latest XCode from the Apple Developer Centre directly? If you go to [the Apple Developer Centre](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) you can manually download XCode 4.5.2 and install it on your machine.  If you upgrade this way the App store will show that your XCode installation is up-to-date btw.

Incidentally, the latest XCode installs in the Applications folder.  Check if XCode 4.1 is installed in Applications as well -- in the past XCode was installed in a special Developer folder, though I think XCode 4.x.x has always been installed in Applications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just try by the Mac App Store, I don't know I can download it directly. Thank you for the tips

Comment: If you have a paid (or free) developer account, you can download various future, present and past versions of Xcode, but rolling into the new App Store for delivery and updates is generally much better for people that choose to have the latest shipping version for testing mobile safari in the iOS simulator. You are right for the general case - especially if you are shipping code and need to keep multiple versions for past frameworks and such.