# How can I (re)create development and build tools on a corrupt installation?

Tags: xcode, homebrew, unix

On my previous computer I had Xcode working nicely; on my present computer, with Homebrew installed, gcc and make are present in /Developer/usr/bin but not /usr/bin. On the whole when I try to download and build http://JonathansCorner.com/download/tms1_4.tar.gz, I can find bits and pieces of the tools used to do things, but when invoked from its present path it doesn't recognize #include <stdio.h> type includes.

How can I reinstall Xcode, Homebrew, and anything else to get a fresh and working build so I can run make && make install?

Answer (score 3):

Reinstalling XCode and updating Homebrew should be enough. To do this:

- Try the `uninstall-devtools` script from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/71674/8244) to remove older XCode versions. (If it doesn't work or you can't find it, don't worry about it.)
- Delete the entire /Developer directory if it exists. This is where older versions of XCode live.
- Download and install the latest XCode for your OS version. (The App Store makes this easy.)
- Install the Command Line Tools. In XCode, go to the Apple menu, select Preferences, select the Downloads section, and click Install next to Command Line Tools.
- Update the Homebrew definitions and packages with `brew update && brew upgrade`.

  - If any brewed packages still seem broken, `brew rm` them and `brew install --fresh` to reinstall.
- Edit your shell config file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`) to make sure `/usr/local/bin` is on your path. `brew doctor` can help diagnose this and other issues.

Note that `tms` is designed to install to `/usr/lib` by default, which you won't have permissions to do in a normal OS X setup even once you have all the tools installed, because the OS reserves `/usr` for its own use. You'll probably want to fiddle with the `Makefile` and `tms.h` to get it in to `/usr/local` or `/opt`, which are easier places to drop user-built packages.

If you're feeling ambitious, you could even do `brew create http://jonathanscorner.com/download/tms1_4.tar.gz` to make a Homebrew formula for TMS, making repeated installs easier.

Comment: Very good advice. I might make a plug to run the perl script that [uninstalls the packages and then files that were installed from Xcode.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71662/how-to-can-i-upgrade-xcode-4-1-to-4-5-2-properly) It's slightly cleaner, but won't touch your code or libraries - just cleans the Apple tools and directories.

Comment: That's a good idea, for hygiene. Adding that as an item in my answer.

Comment: Now that's a great answer. If only I had more than one up vote.

Comment: Aw shucks, now you're making me blush.